# Duplicate questions because of migration from Travel:SE

Tags: feature-request

A couple of times (that I know about), people have asked a question on Travel:SE; been told that it is really on topic here; duplicated the question here; ... and then the original question has been migrated from Travel:SE.

One way to handle this is to close one of the questions as a duplicate of the other.  However this isn't as helpful as it might be because usually one question is a copy-and-paste duplicate of the other (so retaining both does nothing for adding diversity to search terms).

Can we have a way of merging a migrated question with a pre-existing exact duplicate?

Comment: Since this is a feature request of the site I think it might be better suited for the main meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mods can usually merge questions which causes answers to move from one question to the other. I am not sure what happens if we merge a migrated question, since if a migrated question gets closed, it gets kicked back to the original site. If you see this happen, flag them for mod attention and we can deal with it. Hopefully we see it as a duplicate before there are any answers, but if not we should be able to merge.